# Custom TypeScript declaration file in npm package not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have created a simple package that contains an index.d.ts at the root. Here is the content:

```
declare var foo: number;
```

I have then created a separate project which adds that package using npm link. In Visual Studio Code, foo is not getting picked up. I have also tried adding "types": "./index.d.ts" to the package.json where index.d.ts resides. It is not working. In my playground project, I have the following tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Why is the index.d.ts not getting picked up by Visual Studio Code in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, how your library package will be included, so first some common rules:

If you `import` the package as module, `index.d.ts` at package root (or with `package.json` entry) will be picked up automatically via [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules).

If package types are just global type declarations (nothing to import from a module), TS would find it automatically in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder, see [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) configuration.

So, let's say you just have `declare var foo: number;` in the file (it is then a global declaration file) and types are under `node_modules/my-lib`, not `node_modules/@types/my-lib`, then you would need to manually tell TS to include it in the compilation.

Easiest way is probably to add it to the `files` property of `tsconfig.json`, which specifies additional files to be included explicitely. See the good example section [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details). An alternative would be to adjust `typeRoots`, but that is probably overkill here.

My guess is there is a second error cause: `npm link` will create a symlink and per default TS uses those paths, the symlinks resolve to (the real paths).

We can fix that by enabling [`--preserveSymlinks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-5.html#the---preservesymlinks-compiler-flag) option (`tsc --preserveSymlinks`) to use location of the symbolic link file instead (see also [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)). What docs say to this option:

> In this mode, references to modules and packages (e.g. imports and ///  directives) are all resolved relative to the location of the symbolic link file, rather than relative to the path that the symbolic link resolves to.

Comment: I love you! Worked like a charm without preserveSymlink :)